# How to make a simple loop through JOptionPane

Tags: java, loops, joptionpane

I'm new and couldn't find the exact answer I was looking for. I am trying to create a very simple loop using JOptionPane where I insert values between 1-10 and keep looping it. If the value is past 10 or below 1 you should ask the User to try again. So far I have this. If the value hits 0, then the program should end.

```
    String ans_s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "Please enter a rating between 1-10 (0 to stop)");
    int number = Integer.parseInt(ans_s);
    if (number > 10 || number < 0) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Please Try Again");
    ans_s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "Please enter a number between 1-10 (0 to stop)");
    number = Integer.parseInt(ans_s);
    }
    else if (number < 10 || number > 0) {
    ans_s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "Please enter a rating between 1-10 (0 to stop)");
 
    }
    else if (number == 0) {
        
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Finished");
    }
```

Nothing seems to loop so I just need some guidance.

Comment: It's not looping because you are lacking a loop of any kind. Surrounding this code should be a loop statement that tests for your end condition. ie - while(number < 0 || number > 10) {} then inside make sure you're updating the value of number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a loop structure,

```
boolean control_statement = true;
while (control_statement) {
    codeInThisMethodWillLoop(); //Until control_statement = false
}
```

or

```
final int maxLoops = 10; //can be any number
for (int loopCounter = 0; loopCounter < maxLoops; loopCounter++) {
    codeInThisMethodWillLoop(); //Until loopCounter = maxLoops
}
```

in your case

```
int number = -1;
while (number != 0) {
    String ans_s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "Please enter a rating between 1-10 (0 to stop)");
    number = Integer.parseInt(ans_s);
    if (number > 10 || number < 0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Please Try Again");
        ans_s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "Please enter a number between 1-10 (0 to stop)");
        number = Integer.parseInt(ans_s);
    }
    else if (number < 10 || number > 0) {
        ans_s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "Please enter a rating between 1-10 (0 to stop)");
    }
    else if (number == 0) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Finished");
    }
}
```